# VS Code extension to hide console.log commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My typescript files are usually littered with `console.log` commands to output values at various stages of execution. Is there a VS Code extension that automatically collapses `.log` commands when they are not clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

there's an extension to delete them on per document basis. nikhilmutkekar.removeconsolelogs

this for atom[enter link description here](https://dev.to/michael/remove-all-consolelogs-using-regex-in-atom) (for vscode is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure about how to collapse them in the editor, but for the console output in the browser, `console.group()` and `console.groupEnd()` work well.

```
console.group();
console.log('First log');
console.log('Second log');
console.log('Third log');
console.groupEnd();
```